Google play App Transfer, things to check
We are transferring a Google Play app from one Google Play developer account to another. The app is linked to Firebase and Google Cloud services.
The Google Cloud Console is managed by a different account than the new developer account. We have access to the new developer account, and its email has been added to the Google Cloud Console, but the services are not working.
Does the owner of the new developer account need to create a separate account to access Google Play services, or does adding the user as an "owner" in the Google Cloud Console automatically grant access to Google Play?
Previously, google play had API access in the Google developer account, but now we no longer see it after new update. How to link google cloud console to google play?


Please read this and this

The best way to do this is to redo all Google Cloud API & firebase linking from scratch, you will keep facing problems like these if you do not.
Even though Google Play will treat it as the same app, firebase & Google cloud platform will not, to them it is a new app with the same id.
You should delete the old projects on both platforms and start from square 1.

thanks for your feedback, after adding the new account email as owner, it started working! will check for issues there and might as well move it, but was looking for transferring existing without creating new one.
